# java.io.IOException: Invalid Http response

Tags: java, httpresponse, httpurlconnection, ioexception

Now before you say there are questions like this I'd like to point out I've looked over most of them without any luck. Also I'm a first timer here so be gentle.

I have this annoyance right now in my current program:

Basically this part of my program uses a search engine to find torrent files.

```
public static ArrayList<String> search(String args) throws IOException {        
    args = args.replace(":", "");

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    URL url = new URL("http://pirateproxy.net/search/" + args + "/");
    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream())); <---- THIS
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        search("The Hobbit: The Desolation of Smaug");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

THE ERROR:

```
java.io.IOException: Invalid Http response
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at service.ServiceDownloader.search(ServiceDownloader.java:20)
at service.ServiceDownloader.main(ServiceDownloader.java:45)
```

Now the fun part is that it ONLY goes wrong for this movie ("The Hobbit: The Desolation of Smaug"), every other movie works perfectly. I don't understand this. Please do help. (Also I have removed every unnecessary code from the search method)

If I did not put enough information here please ask me for more.

Comment: What is the args value that you are passing at runtime? Did you manually checked opening the same URL that you are trying to access from your code

Comment: "http://pirateproxy.net/search/The Hobbit The Desolation of Smaug/"
Which, if I copy paste into the address bar works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should URL encode the String `The Hobbit: The Desolation of Smaug`, since you have special character there. Ex : space.

Comment: This works! But I still don't understand why. I've had several other movies with space in it that I didn't need to change for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it tripped on the colon (:) not the space. Are there other titles with a colon?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of concatenating strings and needlessly creating interim strings and failing because the url is not encoded, you can use the built in [`UriBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.html) to generate a valid URL

```
URL path = UriBuilder.fromPath("http://pirateproxy.net")
            .path("search")
            .path("some movie ")
            .build()
            .toURL();

// http://pirateproxy.net/search/some%20movie%20
```